# Find and replace HTML text with javascript

Tags: javascript, html

Using a WYSIWYG type web page creator that links up to various databases to pull in information from the clients servers.

One variable is for frequency and has three possible outputs, MO, YR or it is blank.

This is my HTML for one place (this can appear multiple times, just switching out the 1 with the next number)

```
<span style="font-size:24px;"><strong>$@@1_Price</strong></span><span style="font-size:18px;" class="rateFrequency">@@1_rateFrequency</span>
```

I am looking to use javascript to replace the MO or YR with /month and /year and doing nothing when it fills in blank.

Not much knowledge in javascript, so not sure where to begin. Was thinking somthing along the lines of this, but not sure if I am going in the right direction or where to move forward from here

```html
<script>
  window.onload=function change() {
      var frequency = document.getElementsByClassName("rateFrequency");
      if (condition1) {
          block of code to be executed if condition1 is true
      } else if (condition2) {
          block of code to be executed if the condition1 is false and condition2 is true
      } else {
          block of code to be executed if the condition1 is false and condition2 is false
      }
  }
change();
</script>
```

Anything to help me move forward would be great. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming I have understood your requirements correctly, the following code should do the trick, no matter how many "rateFrequency" spans are in the HTML document.

```
window.onload = function(e) {

  function changeFreq() {
    var els = document.getElementsByClassName("rateFrequency"),
    len = els.length;
    while (len--){
      els.item(len).innerText = els.item(len).innerText.replace('MO', '/month').replace('YR', '/year');
    }
  }

  changeFreq();
};
```

No `if` is required here. If the text contained in the span is 'MO', the first `replace` will replace it with '/month' and the second replace won't do anything. If the text contained in the span is 'YR', the first `replace` won't do anything, and the second `replace` will replace it with '/year'. If the text in the span is anything other than 'MO' or 'YR', neither `replace` will do anything, and the text in the span will remain unchanged.

Comment: I think he has an unknown set of spans.  So the solution is good, but you would have to loop.

Comment: Thanks, you're correct. I missed that in the question when I first read it. Will adjust the code now.

Comment: Is there anything else I need to get this to function? I tried pasting it into my script section as is with no luck, and I also iput it in with window.onload and no luck.

Edit: nevermind, added it to the bottom of the page rather than the top and is working now. Thanks a ton!

Comment: I'll update it so that it's called on window.onload()

Answer (score -1):

I have made codepen for you to take a look at.  It uses jquery, which I suggest you use because it is awesome!

Let me know if you have question:
[Example](http://codepen.io/KAPastor/pen/aZvgzG)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 $.each($('.rateFrequency'),function(){
    frq = $(this).text();
    if (frq=='MO'){
     console.log('REPLACE MONTH');
     $(this).text('/month');
    }else if(frq=='YR'){
     console.log('REPLACE YEAR');
      $(this).text('/year');
    }
  }) 
})
```

Comment: Downvote reason: The original question asks for a solution in javascript, and you've provided a solution that depends on jQuery.

Comment: Fair enough.  I did so because he said he was very new to javascript, so I thought it would be OK to show him what was out there.  I accept the downvote.  (Also thanks for specifying the reason).

Comment: I appreciate the jquery response, and were I not using a WYSIWYG platform, I would be all for it. But it is easier to add straight javascript in this work environment.